# Structured streaming won't write DF to file sink citing /_spark_metadata/9.compact doesn't exist

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, spark-structured-streaming

I'm building a Kafka ingest module in EMR 5.11.1, Spark 2.2.1. My intention is to use Structured Streaming to consume from a Kafka topic, do some processing, and store to EMRFS/S3 in parquet format.

Console sink works as expected, file sink does not work.

In `spark-shell`:

```scala
val event = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", <server list>)
.option("subscribe", <topic>)
.load()

val eventdf = event.select($"value" cast "string" as "json")
.select(from_json($"json", readSchema) as "data")
.select("data.*")

val outputdf = <some processing on eventdf>
```

This works:

```scala
val console_query = outputdf.writeStream.format("console")
.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10.seconds))
.outputMode(OutputMode.Append)
.start
```

This doesn't:

```scala
val filesink_query = outputdf.writeStream
.partitionBy(<some column>)
.format("parquet")
.option("path", <some path in EMRFS>)
.option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/ingestcheckpoint")
.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10.seconds))
.outputMode(OutputMode.Append)
.start //fails
```

Things I tried that didn't work:

1. `sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", "false")`
2. Change format to CSV instead of parquet
3. Change output mode to Complete (only append is supported)
4. Different Trigger intervals
5. `.option("failOnDataLoss", false)` on `readStream`

Some digging into the source code took me here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala
where it says that absence of the .compact file should trigger defaults.

Hence tried: `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.fileSink.log.cleanupDelay", 60000)` to make sure that old batch's metadata isn't being removed before the new batch creates a combined metadata file

What makes this error annoying is that it isn't always reproducible. Without changing a single character in the code, writing to parquet will sometimes work, or won't. I have tried cleaning checkpoint locations, Spark/HDFS logs etc in case the "state" of Spark internals was causing this problem.

Here's the error stacktrace:

```
query: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery = org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryWrapper@56122c1

18/04/09 20:20:04 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: history/1523305060336/_spark_metadata/9.compact doesn't exist when compacting batch 19 (compactInterval: 10)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:174)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:172)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.foreach(NumericRange.scala:73)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog.compact(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:172)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog.add(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:156)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ManifestFileCommitProtocol.commitJob(ManifestFileCommitProtocol.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink.addBatch(FileStreamSink.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:666)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:666)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:666)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch(StreamExecution.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:294)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:294)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:294)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:206)
18/04/09 20:20:04 ERROR StreamExecution: Query [id = 5251fe93-2b6b-4dff-bec3-7801dc7e6417, runId = 083547c1-69b7-40e7-8bf9-3c3af11d4c31] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink.addBatch(FileStreamSink.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:666)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:666)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:666)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch(StreamExecution.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:294)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:294)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:294)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:206)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: history/1523305060336/_spark_metadata/9.compact doesn't exist when compacting batch 19 (compactInterval: 10)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:174)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:173)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog$$anonfun$4.apply(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:172)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.foreach(NumericRange.scala:73)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog.compact(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:172)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog.add(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:156)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ManifestFileCommitProtocol.commitJob(ManifestFileCommitProtocol.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:207)
        ... 20 more
```

Comment: Clearing checkpoint location at every re-run seemed to work but we abandoned EMR soon thereafter. Worth a try

Comment: @maverik What your final take on this. I'm facing the problem right now. Was it just EMR or else ?

Comment: @MaatDeamon seemed to work out for us when we stopped writing to s3. downside: you need a driver node with large (and fast) EBS storage. don't checkpoint in s3, since its not a real filesystem which can support ordering of files etc. finally take it with a grain of salt since we didn't use EMR a long time and migrated to Databricks, if you have enterprise support talk to AWS staff engineers. This is not a Spark problem, more of an AWS glitch.

Comment: You said you quit EMR, but you can use HDFS with it, isn’t it ?

Comment: ^ EMRFS is just a layer on HDFS

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that S3 does not support the read-after-write semantics needed by Spark checkpointing.

[This article](https://blog.yuvalitzchakov.com/improving-spark-streaming-checkpoint-performance-with-aws-efs/) suggests using [AWS EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs) for checkpointing.

S3 remains a good place to ingest data from, or egest data to.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this question by clearing my checkpoint path:

1. remove your checkpoint path:

   `sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -rmr ${your_checkpoint_path}`
2. resubmit your spark job.

Comment: For me also it worked after changing the checkpoint location. Why is it happening like that?

Comment: @Soumendra Looks like the underlying filesystem that EMR uses is very "unstable" and unreliable so when a streaming query checkpoints its state it simply needs a better filesystem (not whatever EMR uses).

Comment: I'd not remove checkpoint directory at every start of a streaming query since the purpose of the directory is to keep state so you won't re-process events and have incorrect results. You should keep a checkpoint directory healthy at all cost and remove it only as your last resort (read: never). What you propose is a workaround not a solution.

Comment: @Jacek Laskowski Master how to keep a checkpoint directory healthy ? what kind of things should be taken care of for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

This error message can show up when the file sink path has changed between re-starts of the structured streaming job or the file system of the output path is unreliable and data can be lost between re-starts.

In case you changed file sink output paths you could copy the missing data from

```
/old/file/sink/path/_spark_metadata/9.compact
```

to

```
/new/file/sink/path/_spark_metadata/9.compact
```

I have given more details on the background in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56390492/illegalstateexception-spark-metadata-0-doesnt-exist-while-compacting-batch-9/66693112#66693112)